# PaginatorHelper is not checking the page number

Tags: cakephp, view-helpers, paginator, cakephp-2.3

I have a problem with the Cakephp2.3 paginator helper. In the 1.3 version, the paginate method was checking if the passed page param has a correct value. Now, it's not working anymore.

For example, if I have a list with 30 results, 10 items per page, then this was redirecting to the last (third) page:

```
mycontroller/index/page:130
```

Now, when I modify the url directly in the browser and pass an invalid page number, it just says there are no results.

This is how I'm using the paginate method:

```
$this->paginate = array(
                'limit' => 10,
                'order' => 'Appointment.start_datetime DESC'
            );
$appointments = $this->paginate('Appointment');
```

Is there something I'm missing?

Thank you in advance.

**UPDATE**

The paginator helper does know how to count the number of pages corectly, but it doesn't seem to care if a correct page number is passed. Here is the output from the view:

```
print_r($this->Paginator->params());
```

shows:

```
Array
(
    [page] => 1
    [current] => 10
    [count] => 30
    [prevPage] => 
    [nextPage] => 1
    [pageCount] => 3
    [order] => Appointment.start_datetime DESC
    [limit] => 10
    [options] => Array
        (
            [page] => 1
        )

    [paramType] => named
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that both Cake version include some code that takes care of a too high `page` parameter:

Cake 1.3: `Controller->paginate()`

```
if ($page === 'last' || $page >= $pageCount) {
    $options['page'] = $page = $pageCount;
} elseif (intval($page) < 1) {
    $options['page'] = $page = 1;
}
```

Cake 2.3: `PaginatorComponent->paginate()`

```
$pageCount = intval(ceil($count / $limit));
$page = max(min($page, $pageCount), 1);
```

But interestingly, in Cake 2.3, this code is placed **after** the call to `find()`, so too late to fetch the records correctly. It may be a never signaled bug.

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to reply, you are of course correct. I solved the problem by modifying the PaginatorComponent->paginate() method and now everything works fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any apps using paginator to play with so this will be blind. You could do something like:

```
$page_count = $this->Paginator->params['paginator']['count'];
$page_requested = $this->request->params['paginator']['page'];

if($page_requested > $page_count){
    //Redirect to last page .....
}
```

Although, I find it hard to believe they would remove this default functionality in 2.x.

I would do a `pr($this->params);` to get the exact indexes in the paginator object that you need.

Comment: I added the params in the question above. The paginator's params are correct, but the redirect is not done. I know, this is stupid especially since it worked in the 1.3 version. Now, I'm thinking the page number validation should be done in the controller, but the Paginator is a helper and should be used in the view, right? Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: How are you sending $appointments to the view? $this->set('appointments', $this->paginate('Appointment')); ? This all looks correct. Nothing really sticks out.

Comment: Yes, the pagination is working, but if I change the param page:4 from the url (and I have only 3 pages), instead of redirecting me to the last page, it tries to show results from page 4 (and of course there are none). I'm pretty sure that CakePHP1.3 was redirecting to a valid page number instead of trying to show a page that doesn't exist.

Comment: This is a problem because I also have a delete function, and if I keep deleting rows from the last page and redirect back to it each time, at some point I will end up with a redirect to a page that has no results on it.